# String is longer than expected, and is treated as multiple inputs

Tags: c, string, input

this is my first post here, and I'm relatively new to C (this is only my 2nd unit on it at uni).

Basically, I'm trying to write a segment of code that asks the user if they wish to continue. If they write "yes", the code continues to loop. If they write no, the code terminates the program. If they write anything else, it just asks again until there's a recognised input. I'm using scanf and printf, and attempting to only use them to create this code.

```
char userInput[4];
userInput[0] = '\0';

while ((strcmp(userInput, "yes") != 0) && (strcmp(userInput, "no") != 0))
{
    printf("Do you want to continue (yes/no) :");
    scanf("%3s", userInput);
}
```

I haven't included the rest of the code, just for simplicity.

For example, my input is

```
xxx
```

the output is

```
Do you want to continue (yes/no) :
```

which is fine. But then, if I input:

```
xxxx
```

the output is:

```
Do you want to continue (yes/no) :Do you want to continue (yes/no) :
```

and if i input

```
xxxxxxx
```

I get

```
Do you want to continue (yes/no) :Do you want to continue (yes/no) :Do you want to continue (yes/no) :
```

It seems like it's almost saving the rest of the characters after the expected length, and sending them to the input straight away or something? I want to build in protection against strings that are too long, but this isn't ideal in my opinion.

I'm sorry if the question is structured badly, any constructive criticism is appreciated. I couldn't find this exact problem anywhere so I thought I'd ask myself.

Comment: `scanf` is only reading 3 chars at a time and leaving the rest in the input buffer. So the next call to `scanf` sees the left over ones and reads them immediately.

Comment: Never use `scanf` for anything. Read an entire line of input with `fgets` (or, better, but not universally available, `getline`), and then parse it by hand -- in this case, that means stripping whitespace and then comparing to "yes" or "no" as you are.

Comment: You can use read, that's way better to understand/learn how does it work

Comment: "It seems like it's almost saving the rest of the characters after the expected length, and sending them to the input straight away or something?" This ain't "seem so", this is exactly what's happening. Why should "it" discard any input? If *your application* doesn't need that input, it's *your* responsibility to read and discard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `scanf("%3s", userInput)` it would read only `3` characters terminated by `'\0'` to the `userInput` buffer. However, if you type more than `3`characters the rest is still present in the input buffer waiting for `scanf`to read it.
You can drain your buffer after every `scanf` avoiding this kind of surprise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
   char userInput[4];
   userInput[0] = '\0';
   int c;

   while ((strcmp(userInput, "yes") != 0) && (strcmp(userInput, "no") != 0))
   {
        printf("Do you want to continue (yes/no) :");
        scanf("%3s", userInput);

        while(1) // drain the input
        {
            c = getchar ();
            if(c=='\n') break;
            if(c==EOF)  return -1;
        }
    }      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm still really new to C, so my question is, what does getchar (); actually do, how does it work? I don't like using things in my code if I don't understand them.
The only other solution I found in my searches was using
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
immediately after the original scanf which I also don't get.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the pitfalls fo using `scanf` for user input. `fgets` or POSIX `getline` are much better choices because they avoid many of the ("What's left in the input buffer?") issues inherent with `scanf`. That being said, it is important to know how to use `scanf` properly.

Using `scanf` is nothing more than an exercise in accounting for (1) What characters were actually read? and (2) What characters remain unread in the input buffer? In order to handle No. 2, you need some way to empty any characters that remain in your input buffer between calls to `scanf` to insure you are not bitten by any that remain. You also have to know that at least a single character remains or you will simply block waiting for input to clear. The standard way of emptying `stdin` is just to loop over any characters that remain until you read the trailing `"\n'` (the result of the user pressing "Enter") or `EOF`. e.g.,

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

(you can also write it as a single `for` statement, e,g. `for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}`, but the while is generally more readable.)

Not it is just a matter of properly handling the input. Since you want to force the user to enter "yes" or "no", the general approach is to loop continually until the input criteria is satisfied. Something you were on the right track with, but didn't quite get there. Instead, you could do:

```
char buffer[1024] = "";         /* don't skimp on buffer size */

for (;;) {                      /* loop continually */
    int rtn;                    /* value to hold return from scanf */
    printf ("Do you want to continue (yes/no): ");  /* prompt */
    rtn = scanf ("%1023[^\n]", buffer);             /* read input */
    if (rtn == EOF) {           /* user canceled input, bail */
        fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (rtn == 1) {        /* value stored in buffer */
        /* check for input meeting criteria */
        if (strcmp (buffer, "yes") == 0 || strcmp (buffer, "no") == 0) {
            empty_stdin();  /* don't leave characters in stdin */
            break;          /* success, break input loop */
        }
    }
    /* handle wrong input */
    empty_stdin();  /* don't leave characters in stdin */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n\n");
}
```

If you approach the read in that manner, you control what remains in the input buffer, not only for each read in the loop, but you insure no characters remain in the buffer from your user input when you leave.

As mentioned above, using scanf correctly, is just an accounting problem where once you know how each *format specifier* behaves, and the effect of *input* or *matching* failures stopping the read at the point of failure, you can answer then questions of (1) What characters were actually read? and (2) What characters remain unread in the input buffer?

A short example may help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char buffer[1024] = "";         /* don't skimp on buffer size */

    for (;;) {                      /* process loop - doing stuff */
        printf ("\nprogram processing....\n\n");
        for (;;) {                      /* input - loop continually */
            int rtn;                    /* value to hold return from scanf */
            printf ("Do you want to continue (yes/no): ");  /* prompt */
            rtn = scanf ("%1023[^\n]", buffer);             /* read input */
            if (rtn == EOF) {           /* user canceled input, bail */
                fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else if (rtn == 1) {        /* value stored in buffer */
                /* check for input meeting criteria */
                if (strcmp (buffer, "yes") == 0) {
                    empty_stdin();  /* don't leave characters in stdin */
                    break;          /* success, break input loop */
                }
                else if (strcmp (buffer, "no") == 0)
                    goto alldone;
            }
            /* handle wrong input */
            empty_stdin();  /* don't leave characters in stdin */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n\n");
        }
    }
    alldone:;

    printf ("that's all folks...\n");
}
```

(**note:** above the `"yes"` and `"no"` responses are compared separately to allow for continued process on `"yes"` or `exit` on `"no"`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_yes_no

program processing....

Do you want to continue (yes/no): what?
error: invalid input.

Do you want to continue (yes/no): obnoxious long line because cat stepped on kbd
error: invalid input.

Do you want to continue (yes/no): yes

program processing....

Do you want to continue (yes/no): yes

program processing....

Do you want to continue (yes/no):
error: invalid input.

Do you want to continue (yes/no): no
that's all folks...
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like it's almost saving the rest of the characters after the expected length, and sending them to the input straight away or something?

Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Those characters are there, sitting in the input buffer, waiting to be consumed, just like the first three characters were at one point in time.

You send characters from your keyboard, through your operating system, into your terminal. Your program, per what you wrote, will accept text until the end of the universe (albeit three characters at a time). As long as there are more characters available, it will eat them, and it doesn't matter how far distributed your keystrokes were in time. C++ has no way of knowing you want it to do anything else.

That being said, by adjusting your semantics (as shown in other answers) it's possible to get behaviour that's more intuitive for a call/response prompt like this.